# Why im not able to use executeScript in my selenium script?

Tags: selenium, execute-script

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor.executeScript;

Comment: Please add the code how exactly you try to execute your script

Comment: This is how Im trying to use that                                                         
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 js.executeScript("document.getElementById('lst-ib').value='chercher tech'");

Comment: what is the error you get

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'executeScript'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need executeScript in your import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```